# remove the border of div containing the active link

Tags: html, css

Ok, I have a list of links in my top menu of my website that each of them is inside a class div. I want to set the border of the active link(current page) to none; but I seem to have some problems in the code!

the top menu links

```
<div class="emp_details_link"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/general';?>" >General</a></div>
<div class="emp_details_link"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/contact';?>" >Contact</a></div>
<div class="emp_details_link"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/Relations';?>" >Relations</a></div>
<div class="emp_details_link"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/Work';?>" >Work</a></div>
```

my CSS:

```
.emp_details_link{
  border:1px solid #000000;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
}
.emp_details_link a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.emp_details_link > a:active{ // poiting to the parent div
  border:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

Comment: none of the links have the class `active`

Comment: The solution will is to add the class `active` to `div.emp_details_link` instead of the anchor element

Comment: I would also recommend looking into jQuery because I find that easier to use for this, though, you face someone not having javascript enabled when viewing.

Comment: But I assume active is the status of the link and not a class name or something like that!

Comment: Arun active is not class it is a state :active the link position that is in active position or opened

Comment: @SahilPopli sorry I thought it is the current page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Jquery to solve this problem, use some class for active link and use jquery for remove the active class this is one method example is following

Script

```
$('.emp_details_link a').on('click',function(){
   $('div').removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

PHP

```
<div class="emp_details_link"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/general';?>" >General</a></div>
<div class="emp_details_link"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/contact';?>" >Contact</a></div>
<div class="emp_details_link"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/Relations';?>" >Relations</a></div>
<div class="emp_details_link"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/Work';?>" >Work</a></div>
```

css

```
.emp_details_link{
  border:1px solid #000000;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
}
.emp_details_link a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.emp_details_link > a:active{ // poiting to the parent div
  border:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:none;
}
.active
{
    border:none;
}
```

and another method with out using jquery, is directly use the class in appropriate page, like I assume now contact is active page

css

```
.emp_details_link{
  border:1px solid #000000;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
}
.emp_details_link a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.emp_details_link > a:active{ // poiting to the parent div
  border:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:none;
}
.active
{
    border:none;
}
```

php

```
<div class="emp_details_link"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/general';?>" >General</a></div>
<div class="emp_details_link active"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/contact';?>" >Contact</a></div>
<div class="emp_details_link"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/Relations';?>" >Relations</a></div>
<div class="emp_details_link"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/Work';?>" >Work</a></div>
```

Comment: It works good but it applies only for a second until the links opens and then it gets back to the first state where as in your code the second link gets active!!

Comment: you have to place the active class change in every page for ex if you want to active for general link you have to remove active in contact and add in general:<div class="emp_details_link active"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/general';?>" >General</a></div>

Comment: I have given another answer look that too

Answer (score 2):

what you want to achieve, can be done this way.

create a separate class `.active`

```
.active
{
    border:none;
}
```

and apply it to the anchor that you clicked, through jQuery/javascript ( and remove from the previous one):

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/rkDFP/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a class for the current page instead.

:active will only work when you click the link - so that the link is now active..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `border:none;` .it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS.

give border to `a` so that it can remove its own styling

```
.emp_details_link{

  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
}
.emp_details_link a{
  text-decoration:none;
  border:1px solid #000000;
}
.emp_details_link a:active{
  border:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:none;
    // something like this
}
```

or make a separate class for this and add it to that element with `JS`

Answer (score 0):

Give main border to `a` tag instead of `div`

```
.emp_details_link{  
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
}
.emp_details_link a{
  text-decoration:none; border:1px solid #000000; display:block
} 
.emp_details_link > a:active{ // poiting to the parent div
  border:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2JLtd/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you have including the link file to all the page follow like this

general

```
<?php
$general='active';
include('link.php');
?>
```

contact

```
<?php
$contact='active';
include('link.php');
?>
```

link

```
<div class="emp_details_link <?php if(isset($general)) echo $general;?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/general';?>" >General</a></div>
<div class="emp_details_link <?php if(isset($contact)) echo $contact;?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/contact';?>" >Contact</a></div>
<div class="emp_details_link <?php if(isset($Relations)) echo $Relations;?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/Relations';?>" >Relations</a></div>
<div class="emp_details_link <?php if(isset($Work)) echo $Work;?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr/employee_details/Work';?>" >Work</a></div>
```